# Convert SQL to lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Hi Guys I am struggling with this SQL statement which I would want to have converted to a lambda expression

```
select Employee.FName,Report.ReportDate,Report.SentDate
from Report
Inner join Employee
on Report.UserId = Employee.UserId
where Employee.UserId in (select UserId from UserInUser where AssignId =3333333) and
Report.Status='Sent'
```

I got the LINQ as

```
from Report in db.Report
join Employee in db.Employee on Report.UserId equals Employee.UserId
where
    (from UserInUser in db.UserInUser
    where
      UserInUser.AssignId == 3333333
    select new {
      UserInUser.UserId
    }).Contains(new { UserId = ()Employee.UserId }) &&
  Report.Status == "Sent"
select new {
  Employee.FName,
  Report.ReportDate,
  Report.SentDate
}
```

But I need it as Lambda expression for my Entity Framework query...

Any assistance appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Is there a good reason for you to be mixing `where in` and `inner join`?

2) EF should take the query syntax just fine. It's basically just sugar for the expression syntax anyway:-

```
var query1 =
    from report in db.Report
    from employee in db.Employee
    from uiu in db.UserInUser
    where report.UserId == employee.UserId
    where uiu.UserId == employee.UserId
    where uiu.AssignId == 3333333
    where report.Status == "Sent"
    select new
    {
        employee.FName,
        report.ReportDate,
        report.SentDate,
    };
```

Or if you prefer explicit joins over multiple from clauses:-

```
var query2 =
    from report in db.Report
    join employee in db.Employee on report.UserId equals employee.UserId
    join uiu in db.UserInUser on report.UserId equals uiu.UserId
    where uiu.AssignId == 3333333
    where report.Status == "Sent"
    select new
    {
        employee.FName,
        report.ReportDate,
        report.SentDate,
    };
```

Or you really want to use the expression syntax:-

```
var query3 =
    db.Report.SelectMany(report => db.Employee, (report, employee) => new {report, employee})
             .SelectMany(@t => db.UserInUser, (@t, uiu) => new {@t, uiu})
             .Where(@t => @t.@t.report.UserId == @t.@t.employee.UserId)
             .Where(@t => @t.uiu.UserId == @t.@t.employee.UserId)
             .Where(@t => @t.uiu.AssignId == 3333333)
             .Where(@t => @t.@t.report.Status == "Sent")
             .Select(@t => new
             {
                 @t.@t.employee.FName,
                 @t.@t.report.ReportDate,
                 @t.@t.report.SentDate,
             });
```

Or if you really want to use the expression syntax *and* prefer `Join` over `SelectMany`:-

```
var query4 =
    db.Report.Join(db.Employee,
                   report => report.UserId,
                   employee => employee.UserId,
                   (report, employee) => new {report, employee})
             .Join(db.UserInUser,
                   @t => @t.report.UserId,
                   uiu => uiu.UserId,
                   (@t, uiu) => new {@t, uiu})
             .Where(@t => @t.uiu.AssignId == 3333333)
             .Where(@t => @t.@t.report.Status == "Sent")
             .Select(@t => new
             {
                 @t.@t.employee.FName,
                 @t.@t.report.ReportDate,
                 @t.@t.report.SentDate,
             });
```

3) If you really really want to use the subselect you can do:-

```
var query5 =
    from report in db.Report
    join employee in db.Employee on report.UserId equals employee.UserId
    where db.UserInUser.Any(x => x.AssignId == 3333333 && x.UserId == employee.UserId)
    where report.Status == "Sent"
    select new
    {
        employee.FName,
        report.ReportDate,
        report.SentDate
    };
```

Or, again, if you prefer the expression syntax:-

```
var query6 =
    db.Report.Join(db.Employee,
                   report => report.UserId,
                   employee => employee.UserId,
                   (report, employee) => new {report, employee})
             .Where(@t => db.UserInUser.Any(x => x.AssignId == 3333333 && x.UserId == @t.employee.UserId))
             .Where(@t => @t.report.Status == "Sent")
             .Select(@t => new
             {
               @t.employee.FName,
               @t.report.ReportDate,
               @t.report.SentDate
             });
```

**Be a little bit careful. I've made some (reasonable) assumptions about which columns in your database are *unique* and which aren't. If my assumptions are wrong, these queries may not all be equivalent and may give you incorrect results.**

Personally I tend to mix and match query/expression syntax depending on which I think is most readable given the query (`query1` in this case imo, but ymmv!). Your organisation might have specific code standards that you should follow in this instance, though. E.g. the place I'm working atm prefers the style of `query4` always.

Comment: @Lain , thanks a lot for the multiple option.... I would have voted up for this but dnt have that rights yet...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var assignId=3333333;
var status="Sent";
var result= 
(
    from report in db.Report
    join employee in db.Employee
        on report.UserId equals employee.UserId
    where db.UserInUser
            .Where(w=>w.AssignId==assignId)
            .Select(s=>s.UserId)
            .Contains(Employee.UserId)
    where report.Status==status
    select new
    {
        employee.FName,
        report.ReportDate,
        report.SentDate
    }
).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks , it worked ...can you please direct me a resource where i can learn complex lambda combinations.... I would appreciate useful links